# Multi Choice user input as Branch: If/else condition

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to know is it possible to create response base on multi choice user input in bot framework composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can refer the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-control-conversation-flow?tabs=v2x) and sample [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao03vlYbXWE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Store the choice in a property (dialog.choice/user.choice) and then use it in the branch condition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).